# INI file parser for C

Tags: c

I need to read/write to INI file in C. It is a little strange for me that I can't find any standard way of doing that. What is the common way of dealing with INI files in C?

I prefer both - platform independent and Linux INI file parser libs.

Comment: do you want some platform independent solution or are you going to use a single platform?

Comment: I prefer both - platform independant and Linux ini file parser libs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [link](http://blog.brush.co.nz/2009/02/inih/) may shed some light on the matter (written by the guy that authored [inih](http://code.google.com/p/inih/) as mentioned by Zagorulkin Dmitry) - I have used [minIni](http://code.google.com/p/minini/) and been happy with it..

Answer (score 0):

I know about this lib.
You could use it http://code.google.com/p/inih/

Comment: nice, boot looks it only for reading and no writing to ini file

Comment: Reading is the hard part, writing is far easier: You'll have to store all values in memory, then just write them by iterating over all sections and key/value pairs, adding them to the file.